# UIView emanate rings matching shape of border

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, core-animation

I have been trying to create a custom view in iOS that emanates rings from its border. I have drawn an ellipse using Core Graphics and I want it to periodically emanate.

I have been looking to use both a CAEmitterLayer and Core Animation to achieve this but really have no idea how to achieve the effect I want. Ideally I would like for the ellipse to emanate a ring about 10 pixels in thickness from the edge of the shape and gently fade as it grows and moves further away.

For my initial attempt I simply just had the ellipse grow and fade every 3 seconds using Core Animation but what I really want if for the ellipse to stay stationary and have another layer which animates.

Any suggestions would be great.

My code has moved on from the initial attempt. But what I have atm is:

```
#import "ThumbView.h"

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ThumbView

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {

    [super drawLayer:layer inContext:ctx];

    // Create the emitter layer and make it the same size as the view.
    CAEmitterLayer *emitterLayer = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
    emitterLayer.frame = self.frame;

    // Apply some attributes to the emitter.
    emitterLayer.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerCircle;
    emitterLayer.renderMode = kCAEmitterLayerOutline;
    emitterLayer.emitterSize = CGSizeMake ( 4, 4 );

    // Create a scale animation that repeats every 3 seconds.
    CAKeyframeAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    scaleAnimation.duration = 3.0f;
    scaleAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
    scaleAnimation.values = @[@1, @1.5f, @1.5f];
    scaleAnimation.keyTimes = @[@0, @0.5, @1];

    // Create a fade animation that repeats every 3 seconds.
    CAKeyframeAnimation *glowAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    glowAnimation.duration = 3.0f;
    glowAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
    glowAnimation.values = @[@1, @0, @0];
    glowAnimation.keyTimes = @[@0, @0.5, @1];

    [emitterLayer addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scale"];
    [emitterLayer addAnimation:glowAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];

    if ( !self.pressed ) {
        [layer insertSublayer:emitterLayer above:layer];
    } else {
        [emitterLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }

}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // Drawing code. Draw an elipse here.
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor ( context, self.thumbColour.CGColor );
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect ( context, rect );

}


@end
```

So what I have been trying to do is to create the emitter layer within the drawLayer:inContext: delegate method; apply animations to it; and add it as a sublayer to the views layer.

Comment: Can you add the code of what you have tried so far as it is easier to help then

Comment: Would you consider just using a .gif and using something like http://blog.stijnspijker.nl/2009/07/animated-and-transparent-gifs-for-iphone-made-easy/ to allow gifs to work? I think it could save you a ton of trouble.

Comment: I think you are probably right. It would save a lot of grief. I am not adverse to using gifs. I was just trying to do it more efficiently through code, but that may be more trouble than it is worth. Having done more research I think using an emitterLayer will be overkill.

Comment: Glad I found a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using one or more CAShapeLayer objects, and animating the scale of the CGPath that is installed in the shape layer.

Shape layers animate changes to their path by default.

You should be able to create a set of shape layers that stroke the ellipse that you want to draw, and change the scale setting of those paths to  get the effect you want.

Comment: Is what you are suggesting to change what is returned from - (CALayer *)layer to CAShapeLayer; create the ellipse in this layer; add other sublayers that stroke the ellipse and animate the stroke layer's path to scale? Sounds sensible

Comment: What do you mean by change what is returned from -(CALayer *)layer? Do you mean create a custom subclass of UIView that implements the class method + (Class)layerClass to make the backing layer a shape layer? Yes, you could do that. Then the main layer of your view could be a shape layer, and you could add other shape layers that would cause your view to emit concentric shapes that grow out from the main shape.

Comment: That is what I meant. I typed out the wrong method. Got it working a treat. Thanks